# Caching of bitmaps in android

Tags: android, caching

I am building a simple photo sharing application. When I click camera icon, user would be able to take photo using the camera app. And when he saves that photo, it will be shown in grid view including the previously taken photos.
This means, when I take nth photo in an album , i should draw the bitmap for the other (n-1) bitmaps again. This would happen continuously. Even if i delete a pic, i should redraw (n-1) pictures using bitmaps again.

I am thinking of using some caching of created bitmaps and using it again.

Is there any caching recommendation for this scenario.

Thanking you in advance..

Regards,
Mugil

Comment: I answered, but I still want to ask the question why you need to redisplay the other n-1 bitmaps again?  Is it possible to keep the history around and only display the new one?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. When people take photos, I just want to show the photos in gridview so that they could see all the photos that were taken previously..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a good place to cache icons: make a subclass of Application.

"Application" sticks around for the life of your application, regardless of which activities come and go.  Even if you exit the app and do something else for a while, the app isn't necessarily terminated.

In your subclass, create your hash, array, or whatever to hold your icons.

Comment: They are not icons. They are bitmaps of the taken pictures in smaller scale. Will your suggestion still hold true in my case?

Comment: "Application" has the longest life of any of your objects so, yes, you can cache bitmaps there, too.